# Installation of Explore package in Hydro

Tags: ros, explore, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install the Explore package (http://wiki.ros.org/exploration) in Hydro. It seems that a lot of the functions used in explore refer to external packages which have since been updated, leading to error in the installation process.

Has anyone successfully gotten explore working in Hydro who is willing to share their installation process?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193395/installation-of-explore-package-in-hydro/) by [crzx5](https://answers.ros.org/users/20244/crzx5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

explore has been out of commission for quite some time, try http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0